# Reverse engineering checksum calculation for Proflame 2 RF remote

Tags: cryptography, protocols, checksum, lfsr

### Intro

The SIT Proflame family of fireplace controllers is used in many brands of fireplaces.
It uses an RF remote that transmits on 315MHz.

I would like to be able to generate valid command packets for arbitrary serial numbers to control my fireplace using a custom microcontroller with RF transmitter. Ultimately I intend for this to be used with a Home Assistant integration I'm creating, so that anyone can use it to control their fireplaces in this way, hence the need to be able to do it for arbitrary serial numbers.

Much of the calculation of the checksum is already known. What is not known what exactly causes the checksum values for remotes with different serial numbers to be different. The hope is that the serial number of the remote somehow is used to modify the checksum calculation and this modification can be reverse engineered. This is what this question is about.

Given the information available on the web it feels we are very close to being able to achieve this. The missing step is to find out what goes into making the checksum calculation unique for each remote's serial number.

Unfortunately I don't understand this well enough yet to come up with my own solution, so any pointers would be appreciated.

### Details

#### Previous efforts

There have been previous efforts to reverse engineer the protocol and its checksum algorithm.

What I assume to be the original research by John Ellinwood is available here: https://github.com/johnellinwood/smartfire

A more detailed discussion around the checksum calculation and potential bit masks is available here: https://github.com/merbanan/rtl_433/issues/1905

#### Packet format

Sample Packet: `a4ed02013ecab5`

| Serial | Version | Command 1 | Command 2 | Checksum 1 | Checksum 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `a4ed` | `02` | `01` | `3e` | `ca` | `b5` |

This structure is reverse engineered. The version field is my guess as all packets I've seen reported so far are from Proflame 2 remotes and that field is consistently `0x02` on those packet captures. There is a Proflame 1 remote that shares the same [FCC ID](https://fcc.report/FCC-ID/T99058402300) ([Schematics](https://fcc.report/FCC-ID/T99058402300/673119), [Block Diagaram](https://fcc.report/FCC-ID/T99058402300/673115)) and housing design as the version 2 remote.

The packet length is fixed and does not vary, the serial and version bytes never changes for any one given remote.

#### What we know about checksum calculation

The following information has been reverse engineered so far:

1. Checksum 1 and Checksum 2 are independent of each other and correspond to Command 1 and Command 2 respectively (i.e. if Command 1 changes but Command 2 does not, Checksum 1 will change but Checksum 2 will not).
2. Checksum 1 and 2 are calculated in the same way. The checksum can be calculated with the following expression:

   `checksum = (init ^ ((cmd&0xf0) << 1) ^ (cmd&0xf0) ^ ((cmd&0xf0) >> 4) ^ (cmd&0x0f) ^ ((cmd&0x0f) << 5)) & 0xff` ([Source](https://github.com/merbanan/rtl_433/issues/1905#issuecomment-1019785992))

   The value for `init` is the missing piece. The `init` value is different for Command 1 and Command 2 calculations.
3. Packets with the same command bytes generate different checksums on different remotes. Therefor it could be assumed that the serial number is a factor in determining the `init` value for each calculation.
4. For the data that we already have in the form of packet captures it is easy to brute force the values of `init`. So we can technically already calculate the checksum for remotes that we have known valid packet captures for.

I'm trying to figure out whether we could randomly generate a serial number, hopefully derive the necessary values for checksum calculation, and then send valid commands to the controller to pair our custom remote with it. The controller can pair with a new remote by putting the receiver into pairing mode and sending one "on" and one "off" signal from the remote. This would allow us to replace a defective or lost remote.

### Sample Data

Here is a compilation of packet captures from different remotes: [Proflame 2 packet captures on GitHub gists](https://gist.github.com/kaechele/d81f3e5b822c96c89a7d1aeedbe0e72b)

For convenience, the corresponding (brute forced) init values (referred to as C and D in the original research) for the serials in this file are:

| Serial | Init1 (C) | Init2 (D) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `21dd` | `7d` | `8b` |
| `47eb` | `61` | `a7` |
| `7d14` | `7e` | `9e` |
| `a4ed` | `eb` | `28` |
| `bf39` | `dd` | `1c` |

#### What else has been tried

Guessing a CRC algorithm for the checksums using `reveng` did not yield any matches for a variety of combinations of message format (using the full packet, using serial bytes separately or combined, including and excluding the version).

Comment: You're asking how to find init? `init = checksum ^ ((cmd&0xf0) << 1) ^ (cmd&0xf0) ^ ((cmd&0xf0) >> 4) ^ (cmd&0x0f) ^ ((cmd&0x0f) << 5))`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am afraid I was a bit unclear. Ultimately I'm trying to figure out how I can craft valid packets for arbitrary serial numbers. As such I need to figure out if and how `init` could be derived from data in the packet. I will amend the question accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that without reverse engineering the firmware code by reading the ROM.   A hash can be generated by mixing a fixed (anything) with the serial number, in any combination of the two.  For example, if S = serial number as a string, the input to the hash function could be  ("hello" +S) or (S + "goodbye") or (interleave the digits of S into the spaces of "p u f f i n s").  Since hashes are 1-way and the input can be any length the number of permutations to  try is effectively infinite.

Comment: and on top of that, the hash function could be CRC32, MD5, SHA1/2, or some home-grown nonstandard shuffling of the serial number.

Comment: @Felix: It was I who didn't understand, thanks for clarifying. So, based on my current understanding, I'd have to agree with Dave S. The `init` value could be anything. Out of curiosity, what happens when you send a command with an invalid checksum? What I'm getting at is perhaps you can send some innocuous command (e.g. a STATUS command if it exists) and try all 256 possible values of init until the command is accepted. That would tell you the value of init for that particular controller.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. My hope was that due to the fact of the checksum calculation itself being rather straightforward it may be similarly feasible to reverse engineer the rest of the algorithm.
I will attempt to see what the controller does with invalid packets.